# jQuery animation only works once or twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm putting together a site where a client has requested a very specific animation in the quicklink scroller.

I've used jquery animate and jquery fadeIn to complete a glass-shine and glow effect on hover, but when hovered once or twice (partcularly if done in quick succession) it stops happening?

Link: http://clientzone.fifteenten.co.uk/visioncode/html

```
$('.fadehover').append('<div class="hover"></div>');
$('.fadehover').hover(  
function() {    $(this).children('div.hover').animate({"left": "+=505px"}, 300);}, 
function() {  $(this).children('div.hover').css({left: "-=" + 505});    
});

$('.fadehover a').hover(    
function() {    $(this).children('div.qlink_glow').fadeIn('fast')}, 
function() {  $(this).children('div.qlink_glow').fadeOut('fast');    
});
```

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated I'm so confused... I've had this happen on other hover effects too

Answer (score 1):

Try `.stop(true,true)` before .animate, .fadeIn and .fadeOut

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs on your element if you hover in before your last animation finished. A first attempt to me would be trying if it helps to stop the animation before beginning a new one:

```
$(this).children('div.qlink_glow').stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast');
```

I'll have to test it, can't say for sure if this will work, just a possibility you could try.

Comment: Hover doesn't have 3 states, so you can't put 3 `function()` in it. And you don't have to copy the whole thing again. You can simply use `.stop().fadeIn('fast')` and `.stop().animate({"left": "+=505px"}, 300)`. The idea is good thou and it might be worth tying.

Comment: Afraid the old stop trick doesn't seem to have done it? see link above, the animate still doesn't appear after one or two 'animations'. bahh!